# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax not able to alter a table to make a foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Hi I am new to mysql so help me please.
I am trying to alter a table called order and make a foriegn key in it.
There is a field user_id is this table and I want to assign it foreign key this is the query I am using

```
alter table order
add constraint foreign key u_id(user_id) references user (user_id) on update cascade on delete cascade;
```

There is a user table with user_id as primary key and I am getting this error.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order add constraint foreign key u_id(user_id) references user (user_id)' at line 1
```

Can someone point out where I am making my mistake as I am not able to trace out the problem.

Comment: thanx i was able to solve the problem by escaping order with `order`

Comment: Please choose an answer to help others looking for solutions.
You can even answer your own question and choose it as the bet answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER` is a [Reserved Word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).  As documented under [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html):

> If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you *must* quote it whenever you refer to it. (Exception: A reserved word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted.)
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`` ` ``”):
>
> ```sql
> mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
> ```
>
> If the [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks:
>
> ```sql
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...
> mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
> ```

Therefore:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `order`
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY u_id (user_id)
                 REFERENCES  user (user_id)
                          ON UPDATE CASCADE
                          ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Order** is reserved Word in mysql you have to use reserved word as `Order`

Try this

```
alter table `order`
add constraint foreign key u_id(user_id) references user (user_id) on update cascade on delete cascade;
```

Answer (score 1):

order is a reserved MySQL keyword.

Just escape it with anti-quotes ```

```
ALTER TABLE `order` Add ...
```